# How to install anytree in miniconda?

Tags: conda, anytree

I have tried the `conda install anytree` command. But I get a message saying package cannot be found.

Is there a way to install it using conda instead of pip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no reliable<sup>**1**</sup> channels hosting **anytree** in Anaconda Cloud. It is possible to use PyPI together with Conda - Conda literally installs `pip` - just make sure to activate your env before using it.  Be aware that mixing Conda and PyPI can lead to issues (see "[Using Pip in a Conda Environment](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/)").

However, if you're really committed to installing from Conda only, then consider contributing to the community by [adding an install recipe](https://conda-forge.org/#add_recipe) for **anytree** to Conda Forge.

---

<sup>**1** As you can see from [search results](https://anaconda.org/search?q=anytree), there is one channel whose name is unfamiliar, but it only ever uploaded one (now outdated) version for Windows. I don't consider that reliable.</sup>

Comment: Hi Merv, I have not added recipies before, but I will give it a go now. : )

Comment: @pranavap that would be great! You may want to [give the anytree dev a heads up](https://github.com/c0fec0de/anytree/issues), since they seem rather active and may have been considering it themselves or want to help.

Comment: Sure, I'll inform them.